# Onclick event on jQuery dialog box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#wrapper').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Basic Dialog'
});
       
$('#listButton').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
    
});

                 var $navChild = $(".navChild");
                $('.navParent').on("click", "li", function () {
                    if(($(this).children(".navChild").css('display'))=='block'){
                        $(".navChild", this).hide();
                        $(this).removeClass('open');
                    }else{
                        $navChild.hide();
                        $("li").removeClass('open');
                        $(".navChild", this).show();
                        $(this).addClass('open');
                    }

                });
                });
```

```css
.navParent {
    width:200px;
   
}
.navParent a {
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    color:black;
}
.navParent u {
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    color:black;
}

.navParent ul {
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
     margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.navParent li {
     
   margin:0;
   padding:0;    
}
.navParent li.open {
    
   margin:0;
   padding:0;    
}
.navChild li {
     list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;    
}
.navChild {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="listButton">Open List</button>
<div id="wrapper">
<TABLE>
    <DIV>List </DIV>
    <TR>
        <TH>Items</TH>
        <TH>Date</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <ul class="navParent">
                <li> <u>Parent Item</u>

                    <ul class="navChild">
                        <li><a href="#sites">Child Item 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#sites">Child Item 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#sites">Child Item 3</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#sites">Child Item 4</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </TD>
        <TD>07/28/2012</TD>
    </TR>    
</TABLE>
</div>
```

`I have a jQuery dialog box loaded from a parent window with list of data.
I want to load a sublist when the user clicks on the list elements in the dialog.

The onclick event to load the sublist is defined in the parent file. 
When the dialog box is clicked no action is performed.

What am I missing?
Is it because I am using multiple functions within same file or same document.ready function ?

open dialog -

```
$('#Button').click(function () {
    $('#dialogBox').load('', function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        $('#dialogBox').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

function for onclick event -

```
var $navChild = $('.navChild');
$('.navParent').on('click', 'li', function () {
    if (($(this).children('.navChild').css('display')) == 'block') {
        $('.navChild', this).hide();
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $navChild.hide();
        $('li').removeClass('open');
        $('.navChild', this).show();
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }
});
```

HTML content on dialog box -

```
<table>
    <div>Lists</div>
    <tr>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul class="navParent">
                <li>
                    <u>Parent Item</u>

                    <ul class="navChild">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#sites">Child Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#sites">Child Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#sites">Child Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#sites">Child Item 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>07/28/2012</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue but I think it is important. You have a `<div>` as a child of a `<table>` tag. This not allowed. Put the `<div>` outside of your `<table>` tags.

Comment: Added JSFiddle to the question

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your code in following way.

```
$(function() {
    $('#dialogBox').dialog({
        autoOpen:false
    });

    $("#Button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialogBox').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

you can try handling instead of load

```
$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function(event, ui) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Prashanth.Not sure if this will resolve the issue ?

Comment: @Harz I have updated the answer. Please let me know if it works for you. Creating JSFiddle would really help.

Comment: Hey Prashanth, Added JSFiddle. The idea is to load a dialogbox with table. The table will contain list of elements. Upon clicking each list , I want to display a sublist.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is dynamically generated you have to use delegate.
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the issues encountered here were because of IE9 in quirks mode.
It won't support CSS hover(except anchor tags) and few jquery operations are not supported .
Finally had to resort to javascript for achieving onclick event on dialog box.